# Form fields created by jQuery return "undefined" upon submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

UPDATE:
I modified the code using the first commenter's checkNo[] suggestion since I thought it may help, and it's more elegant anyways.

The initial hard coded field group of the form looks pretty much the same except I removed the "1" e.g. "checkNo1" is now just "checkNo"

The jQuery to create the new field groups now just copies the initial code:

```
var checksDiv = $('#checkForms');
var i = $('#checkForms p').length + 1;
var checkForm = $('#checkForms').html(); //COPY THE FIELD GROUP CODE

    $('#addCheck').click(function() {
           $(checkForm).appendTo(checksDiv);
           $('#checkCount').val(i);
           i++;
    });
```

and the loop now looks like this:

```
for (i=1;i <= Request.Form("checkNo").Count; i++){ // LOOP THROUGH CHECKS 

        thisCheck = Request.Form("checkNo")(i);
        thisAmt = Request.Form("amt")(i);
        thisInvoices = Request.Form("invoices")(i);
}
```

The result? It STILL comes up undefined... as if the jQuery generated fields are not there.. but they are. I see them, I fill them out, I see them in the html... they are there, but when I post the form, it's like they vanish.

vvvvvvvvvvv PRE-UPDATE vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

I have a section of my form (where the user can add checks) that looks like this:

```
<div id="checkForms">
  <p>
    <label for="checkNo1">
      <input type="text" id="checkNo1" size="20" name="checkNo1" value="" placeholder="Check Number" />
    </label>
    <label for="amt1">
      | $<input type="text" id="amt1" size="20" name="amt1" value="" placeholder="Amount" />
    </label>
    <br/>
    <label for="invoices1">
      <textarea name="invoices1" id="invoices1" placeholder="Invoice Amt" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
    </label>
  </p>
  <hr/>
</div>

<h3><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="addCheck">Add Another Check</a></h3>

<input type="hidden" id="checkCount" name="checkCount" value="1"> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" class="button sendit">
```

I have jQuery adding new fields like this:

```
var checksDiv = $('#checkForms');
var i = $('#checkForms p').size() + 1;

    $('#addCheck').click(function() {
            $('<p><label for="checkNo' + i +'"><input type="text" id="checkNo' + i +'" size="20" name="checkNo' + i +'" placeholder="Check Number" /></label> | $<label for="amt' + i +'"><input type="text" id="amt' + i +'" size="20" name="amt'+ i +'" placeholder="Amount" /></label><br/><label for="invoices' + i +'"><textarea name="note" placeholder="Invoice Amt" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea></label><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remCheck">Remove</a></p><hr/> ').appendTo(checksDiv);
            $('#checkCount').val(i);
            i++;
    });
```

This works fine, they show up....

Then upon submission, I'm accessing the values like this:

```
for (i=1;i <= checkCount; i++){
    thisCheck = Request.Form("checkNo"+i);
    thisAmt = Request.Form("amt"+i);
etc....
```

The first group of "hard coded" fields work fine, but everything that was created dynamically comes up "undefined". I've also tried it like this:

```
for (i=1;i <= checkCount; i++){
    thisCheck = "checkNo"+i;
    thisCheck = Request.Form(thisCheck);
etc....
```

and verified that it is requesting the correct form field name.

Comment: `$(collection).size()` has been deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. Use `$(collection).length` instead (note the lack of parentheses - it is a property so there is no overhead of a function call).

Comment: What is `Request`? A server-side or client-side object? Why don't you use `checkNo[]` names?

Comment: 'Request' is server side.. the form posts to the same page that it's on, and the JS that requests the values is in the code before any of the HTML

Comment: @undefined I tried re-writing the whole thing to use the checkNo[] as I think you mean. So now the jQuery that makes the new field group just copies the original one and there are no number specification e.g. field names 'amt1' & 'amt2' are both 'amt' and my for loop becomes:

`
    for (i=1;i <= Request.Form("checkNo").Count; i++){    
      thisCheck = Request.Form("checkNo")(i);
      thisAmt = Request.Form("amt")(i);
`... but it still just ignores any of the input fields the jQuery created >:(

Answer (score 0):

The serverside code that you've posted should work, but you've omitted the `etc....` which would be interesting.

There is a textarea named `invoices1` in the hardcoded part, but in the dynamic part you didn't create a textarea `'invoices' + i` , the name of the textarea is `note` (without an index).

When you try to access these textarea's with the same procedure as used with the other fields, it will fail.

Comment: Good eye... I changed the text area name and id. Indeed this would have failed. But the others should work no? The 'etc...' is just me accessing the textarea in the same way and then parsing the contents.

Comment: The others should work, I agree. I don't see other issues with the code you've posted. Can you post the data that have been received by the serverside script?

Comment: Is there a way to see all the posted data at once?